# Can multiple camel routes cause a very large number of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, integration, apache-camel, routes

I will clarify my question.

I have a task to integrate two systems: a frontend serving html and backend which gives data to frontend.
Backend have a very large REST api so I have to use multiple routes.
I planned to use single camel context and wrap all routes into it.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring">
    <from uri="direct:data"/>
    <to uri="ahc:http://localhost/data"/>
    <!--And so on. More than 70 routes-->
</camelContext>
```

Then, I planned to invoke the route using @Produce annotation on service method as adviced in [Hiding middleware article](http://camel.apache.org/hiding-middleware.html)

```
public interface Service {
    String data();
}

public class MyBean {
    @Produce(uri = "direct:data")
    protected Service producer;

    public void doSomething() {
        // lets send a message
        String response = producer.data();
    }
}
```

As I understand information taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149557/does-camel-create-a-thread-for-each-route) and [here](http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html) I'll end up with additional 70 thread in my app (one for each route). I fear that it can cause a serious performance hit and while the backend api will grow the thread number will grow with it. Is it correct? How can I avoid this if it's true? As I understand, I can't employ ExecutorService thread pool in this case.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you will not end up with a thread per route. The threading module is often tied to the threading model of the consumer (eg the route input).

For example a route that uses a timer component will use a scheduled thread pool (1 thread). And the JMS component will use 1 or more threads, depending on if you set concurrentConsumers=N, etc.

The direct component is like a direct method invocation and it uses the caller thread, so there is 0 new threads for that threading model.

If all your 70 routes uses the AHC in the < to > then you may want to re-use the same endpoint, so you reuse the thread pool of the AHC library. Or alternative to configure a shared pool to be used for all AHC endpoints.

And btw this question was also posted on the Camel user forum / mailinglist: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Can-multiple-camel-routes-cause-a-very-large-number-of-threads-tp5736620.html